# crystal Report Vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

i have a table that is create in sql server 2005.
I want a report of this table.

The header are Customer Name,No,Part Name,Part Price,No Of Quntity,Total Price,,,,

How can Arrange it in the crystal report Where Customer Name is only single time .......and Other detail is more than one......
and i want them in a Column format then is a in Vartical Align.....
How can i do so.......
It is look like

```
customer Name:- Neeil


No  PartName      PartPrice       NoOfQuntity  TotalPrice

1   hard_disk       3000              2        6000
```

Comment: No problem! For future questions, the "10101" button formats code, and the quote button formats a quotation taken from someplace else (like an error message, another website, etc.) Little formatting tricks like this can help make your question easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a group for Customer Name field and put the other fields in the Details section below that group.

Comment: Here's a collection of "how to" type articles:  http://aspalliance.com/articles/LearnCrystalReports.aspx     And of course you can always ask questions here if you get stuck.